# how to disable focus selection in the tab bar item?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, swift2, tvos, apple-tv

The menu items at the top are selected on roll over. I’ll like the user to highlight an item and then click it to select it.

-> When the user moves to other menu items the selected blue colour goes with it (following the cursor). If user clicks the item, the selected blue colour will be replaced wit the new item, if not as soon as the user leaves the menu bar, the blue will remain in the current menu item.

Example:

The current selected item is "On Demand” in blue, because it’s the page we are at.
User clicked left on the remote: “Search” text will become blue, On Demand will change to white. Main page remains in the screen.
If User clicks in Search and leaves the menu bar: Next time the user visits the menu Search will be blue.
If User doesn’t click any item and leaves the menu bar: Next time the user visits the menu On Demand will be blue.
Menu bar should go away ( roll up) if user is in any video thumbnail.

Like this.
[image]

I want like this.[image]

Comment: Sorry to interrupt this question, but since tvOS 9.1 came out, have you been able to keep using the white colored items for the non-focused state?

Comment: My question is that. Can i move to other tab bar item without load a view controller. When i will tap on the particular item then the related controller load.

Comment: @SankalapYadurajSingh This is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a behavior of UITabBarController that you can change.  It would be non-trivial, but you could write your own custom view controller container that worked in this way.